# Using the MonoTouch.Dialog feature to create an application similar to the SMS application

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, sms, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to learn using MonoTouch. I am basically trying to create something similar to the sms message application that is built into the iphone.

I want the Edit button and a add button within the root element. Is this possible?

Im creating the root element like

```
var root = new RootElement ("My Items");
Section section = new Section();
foreach (var item in GetData()) {
    var element = new RootElement(item.ItemName,0,0) {
        new Section(item.Description)
    };
    section.Add(element);
}
root.Add(section);
```

What do I need to do to add the 2 buttons and load the different views?

Comment: Where on the UI do you want the two buttons? On the NavBar? on a Toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably adding the root to a dialog view controller,

```
var dv = new DialogViewController(root,true);
```

In this case, just initialize the buttons for the navigation items of the view controller

```
dv.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("Edit", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,null);
```

and so on and set up event handlers for dv.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem.Clicked.

That should do it!